# XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2

Tags: xcode, plist

i just got an error from Xcode which says:

> unable to read property list from file: /Users/riccardogambardella/Downloads/codecanyon-9O3RHLEa-fluxstore-woocommerce-flutter-ecommerce-full-app/ios/Runner/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.)

here's the my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>FluxStore</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>inspireui.com</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>fb430258564493822</string>
                </array>
            </array>
     </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.412823237422-pf5dr3f75n6r201u24ocioin54u3cseq</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>firebaseDynamicLink</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.inspireui.mstore.flutter</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>paytmMID</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>430258564493822</string>
    <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
    <string>9def0493cb40104fa311ee9e1086d264</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>FluxStore</string>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FirebaseDeepLinkPasteboardRetrievalEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca-app-pub-7432665165146018~2664444130</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>paytm</string>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the camera for QR Code or Barcode scanner feature which can be access from the search bar</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need current location access</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Get your current location for delivery</string>
    <key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you. &quot;Ask App Not to track&quot; will limit Advertisement network&apos;s ability to deliver relevant ads to you but will not reduce the number of ads you receive.</string>
    <key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the photo library to select a profile photo which will be used as a chat image for the Chat Feature.</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>en</string>
        <string>hi</string>
        <string>es</string>
        <string>fr</string>
        <string>ar</string>
        <string>ru</string>
        <string>id</string>
        <string>ja</string>
        <string>ko</string>
        <string>vi</string>
        <string>ro</string>
        <string>tr</string>
        <string>it</string>
        <string>de</string>
        <string>pt</string>
        <string>hu</string>
        <string>he</string>
        <string>th</string>
        <string>nl</string>
        <string>sr</string>
        <string>pl</string>
        <string>fa</string>
        <string>uk</string>
        <string>bn</string>
        <string>ta</string>
        <string>cs</string>
        <string>sv</string>
        <string>fi</string>
        <string>el</string>
        <string>km</string>
        <string>kn</string>
        <string>mr</string>
        <string>ms</string>
        <string>bs</string>
        <string>lo</string>
        <string>sk</string>
        <string>sw</string>
        <string>zh</string>
        <string>my</string>
        <string>sq</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Any suggestion about that problem? Thanks in advice

Comment: What do you mean with show the code, it's already shown in the post

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your plist. Here is the correct version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>FluxStore</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>inspireui.com</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb430258564493822</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.412823237422-pf5dr3f75n6r201u24ocioin54u3cseq</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>firebaseDynamicLink</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.inspireui.mstore.flutter</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>paytmMID</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>430258564493822</string>
    <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
    <string>9def0493cb40104fa311ee9e1086d264</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>FluxStore</string>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FirebaseDeepLinkPasteboardRetrievalEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca-app-pub-7432665165146018~2664444130</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>paytm</string>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the camera for QR Code or Barcode scanner feature which can be access from the search bar</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need current location access</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Get your current location for delivery</string>
    <key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you. &quot;Ask App Not to track&quot; will limit Advertisement network&apos;s ability to deliver relevant ads to you but will not reduce the number of ads you receive.</string>
    <key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the photo library to select a profile photo which will be used as a chat image for the Chat Feature.</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>en</string>
        <string>hi</string>
        <string>es</string>
        <string>fr</string>
        <string>ar</string>
        <string>ru</string>
        <string>id</string>
        <string>ja</string>
        <string>ko</string>
        <string>vi</string>
        <string>ro</string>
        <string>tr</string>
        <string>it</string>
        <string>de</string>
        <string>pt</string>
        <string>hu</string>
        <string>he</string>
        <string>th</string>
        <string>nl</string>
        <string>sr</string>
        <string>pl</string>
        <string>fa</string>
        <string>uk</string>
        <string>bn</string>
        <string>ta</string>
        <string>cs</string>
        <string>sv</string>
        <string>fi</string>
        <string>el</string>
        <string>km</string>
        <string>kn</string>
        <string>mr</string>
        <string>ms</string>
        <string>bs</string>
        <string>lo</string>
        <string>sk</string>
        <string>sw</string>
        <string>zh</string>
        <string>my</string>
        <string>sq</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment, this is an answer, not the question.